# How do you get Perforce changelist number through Perforce's command-line interface or API from Unreal Engine?

Tags: debugging, perforce, unreal-engine4

I have a debugging tool that dumps information to a file from an Unreal Engine plugin about the current state of the application.  Is there a Perforce command-line command (via P4) or API call that can be used to get the latest changelist number from perforce. I know the command p4 changes -m1 -s submitted [stream] exists.  But, I don't know how to get the current stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
p4 changes -m1 //clientname/...
```

to get all changes submitted to paths mapped to the current client (which for a stream client will be the same as "the current stream").

If you don't know the current client, you can do `p4 set P4CLIENT` or `p4 info`.  The various APIs all have some equivalent of `p4 set P4CLIENT`, e.g. ClientApi::GetClient in the C++ API, and all the APIs can run server commands like `info`.

Alternatively, if you know the client root (which is probably the same as the Unreal project directory?) you can use that:

```
p4 changes -m1 C:\project\...
```

or, if that's your current working directory, just:

```
p4 changes -m1 ...
```